# como abrir mi ventana modal con un button desde js

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

```js
< script >
  export const card = (id, title, description, image) => {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      let html =
        `<article class="message is-success mb-2">
    <div class="message-header">
      ${title}
      <button class="delete delet" data-id="${id}"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="message-body">
      ${description}
    </div>`;
      if (image) {
        html += `<img src = "${image}" class = "image">`;
      }
      (function() {
        $(function() {
          html += `<button clas="edit button is-warning" id="btn-button" data-bs-toggle="modal"
    data-id="${id}">EDITAR</button>`;
          $('#btn-button').on('click', function() {
            $('#exampleModal').modal();

          })

        })
      })
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-ventana" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
    nueva nota
  </button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="columns">


    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">

            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">nueva nota</h1>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <!-------------------formulario------------------------->
            <div class="column is-half">
              <form action="" id="task-form" class="box">
                <label for="task-title">Title:</label>
                <input type="text" name="task-title" id="task-title" class="input" placeholder="Title">
                <label for="task-description">Descripción:</label>
                <textarea class="textarea my-1" name="task-description" id="task-description" placeholder="Task Descripción" rows="5"></textarea>
                <input type="file" name="file-task" id="file-task">
                <progress class="progress is-link" clas="progress is-small is-primary" value="" max="100">15%</progress>
                <img id="image" src="" alt="" width="250px" class="image">
                <button id="btn-task-save" class="button is-success">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

he hecho una app web hace el trabajo de una app de notas en donde ingresas titulo, informacion y agregas una image le e hecho con js y boostrap y firebase, en donde tengo 2 botones, un botón abre el modal para ingresar una nueva tarea y el segundo botón debe abrir el modal para actualizar o modificar la información. pero ese botón no abre mi modal para actualizar,pero el botón esta creado desde lenguaje js.
ya he intentado por funciones y desde onclick().